# Help! Have I Messed Up My Fusion Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, imac, ssd

Last week my late 2012 iMac was running slow and generally not working well, I erased the hard drive to reinstall a fresh copy of Mac OS but somehow messed up the erase (Reading online I think the fusion drive somehow split), I ended up with no operating system and when I turned my iMac on there was just a question mark. I followed some info online about repairing a split drive using terminal and somehow managed to get the original (2012) operating system installed and then updated to the latest version, although it is running now (not great still) I am not sure if everything is correct?
Can someone who knows how these things work please take a look at the provided images of the drives and tell me if all is ok or have I still messed something up??[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know enough about Fusion drives to properly help, but for those who do, could you copy/paste into your question the results of these commands in Terminal - `diskutil cs list` &  `diskutil list`

Comment: I cannot add anymore images as I am a new user, it says I can only add up to 8, should I just delete one of the above images? when I type diskutil cs list into terminal it says "no core storage logical volume groups found" typing in diskutil list however does give info.

Comment: post it as text, then select it & hit ctrl/k which will format it as code. The fact that `cs` produces no result is actually a valid test.

Comment: I have managed to add the results to the bottom of the post now.